# MVC ASP.NET display count of group by result in View using Razor code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, group-by

I'm trying to use this in the controller to get group all Category together and Count the total of each Category.

```
        //Report
        public ActionResult Report()
        {
            var reports =
         db.Product
         .GroupBy(r => r.CategoryName)
         .Select(r => new { Name = r.Key, Count = r.Count() });
            return View(reports);
        }
```

How to access and display the Count and CategoryName in the View? I want to display it like this:

```
CategoryName     Count
P1                 2
P2                 3
P3                 4
P4                 2
```

I have something like this in the Report.cshtml but it's not working:

```
@model IEnumerable<SiteKitBMI.Models.Product>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Count)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Count)
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Can anyone shine some light onto this?? 
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: how is it not working? error? empty screen?

Comment: Your not returning `IEnumerable<Product>` to the view (your code would be throwing an exception). Create a view model (say `ProductVM`)containing properties `Name` and `Count` and project your query into it, - `select r => new ProductVM { ... }` and then it to a view with `@model IEnumerable<ProductVM>`

Comment: First you need to create the list and use view bag to send it on view and then get it by type casting it then you can use the same in the foreach loop .

Comment: Can you show us what you expecting and what is currently showing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller query is returning a collection of anonymous objects to a view which expects a collection of `Product` and will there for throw a *The model item passed into the dictionary is of type ... but this dictionary requires a model item of type ...* exception.

Since `Product` does not contain a property `Count`, you need to create a view model to represent what you want to display in the view

```
public class ProductQuantitiesVM
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

and then project your query to a collection of `ProductQuantitiesVM`

```
var reports = db.Product.GroupBy(r => r.CategoryName)
    .Select(r => new ProductQuantitiesVM()
    {
        Name = r.Key,
        Count = r.Count()
    });
return View(reports);
```

and finally, change the view to use `ProductQuantitiesVM`

```
@model IEnumerable<ProductQuantitiesVM>
....
```

Comment: I orginally have issue doing toList() from iqueryable with error saying it's not supported.  So I changed it around a little. The main underlying is with the CategoryName property containing conditional statements which relies on values from another property.

Comment: But yeah, I've now used the ProductQuantitiesVM view model class approach and fixed that up and it's working perfectly :)